# Query-builder in Symfony2, known function Month error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, customization, dql, query-builder

I have a problem with Symfony2 QueryBuilder.

I have the following code which throws an error

```
$repositorio= $em->getRepository('SingUserBundle:Data');
$consulta= $repositorio->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->where('d.usuario = :usuario')
    ->andWhere ('MONTH(d.fecha) = :mesActual')
    ->setParameter('usuario', $usuario->getId())
    ->setParameter('mesActual', $mesActual)
    ->getQuery();
$totaldatos= $consulta->getSingleResult();
```

The error is:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 80: Error: Expected known function, got 'MONTH'
```

Comment: How did you solved your problem?

Comment: yes @JeanValjean finally, I am going to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fix up my problem!
and finally I didn´t use MONTH

```
$fecha=new \DateTime("now");
            $fecha->setDate(DATE_FORMAT($fecha, 'Y'),DATE_FORMAT($fecha, 'm'),01);

            $qb= $this->createQueryBuilder('ud')
                ->where('ud.usuario = :identifier')
                ->andWhere('ud.fecha >= :identifier2')
               ->setParameters(array('identifier'=>$user,'identifier2'=> $fecha));
```

I took the date one month laterand did the query.

I hope to help someone!

Answer (score 8):

As **Gremo** reported in his answer, there is no builtin `month` function. So, you have to extend DQL to have the month function.

If you are not skilled to do that or you have no time, I suggest to install the [DoctrineExtensions Mysql Function Pack](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions), available for free on Gitbub repository.
It includes many useful **DQL** function, even included the `month` function.

Comment: I have installed this extensions pack, but i still receive the error (expected function, got YEAR), I got the extension by composer, and we are using annotations mapping not YAML, so is there any trick to enable this extension pack with annotations driver?
We are using this extensions pack alongside Gedmo, is it ok?

Answer (score 3):

Simply as the message says: query builder doesn't support `MONTH` function. Either write a [user defined function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) or use [native SQL with a result set mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

Answer (score 1):

It was an easy solution to solve this problem, at least for me:

```
$month= 04;
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$result = $qb->select('yd')
->from('RocketSellerTwoPickBundle:YearDates','yd')
->where($qb->expr()->like('yd.date', ':month'))
->setParameter('month', '%-' . $month . '-%')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved using the following code:

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $startDate = date( 'Y-m-' ) . '01'; // First day in current month
    $endDate   = date( 'Y-m-t' ); // Last day in current month

    $qb
        ->addSelect( 'l' )
        ->from( 'BackendBundle:Local', 'l' )
        ->join('l.inscriptions', 'i')
        ->where( 'i.date >= :startDate' )
        ->andWhere( 'i.date <= :endDate' )
        ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $query->setQueryCacheLifetime( 3600 );
    $query->setResultCacheLifetime( 3600 );
    $query->useQueryCache( true );

    return $query->getResult();
```

At least works for me, hope you can find useful.