# Doctrine 2.2 DQL DATE GROUP BY

Tags: php, date, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to execute this query:

```
public function historyLoginAction() {
    $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $em->getConfiguration()->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DATE', 'TB\UserBundle\DQLFunctions\DateFunction');

    $dql   = "SELECT COUNT(u.id),u.lastLogin, DATE(u.lastLogin) AS groupDate FROM UserBundle:User u GROUP BY groupDate ORDER BY u.lastLogin DESC";

    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        12/*limit per page*/
    );
```

DateFunction:

```
<?php

namespace TB\UserBundle\DQLFunctions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

class DateFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    private $arg;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf('DATE(%s)', $this->arg->dispatch($sqlWalker));
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->arg = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

According to these pages...

[Use a DATE() function in a WHERE clause with DQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272224/use-a-date-function-in-a-where-clause-with-dql?answertab=active#tab-top)

[Doctrine: Group by date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508870/doctrine-group-by-date-ranges?answertab=active#tab-top)

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1236

When i var_dump the query result before $paginator

```
    var_dump($query->getResult());die;
```

I get my output (so the DQL is good right?)

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      'lastLogin' => 
        object(DateTime)[968]
          public 'date' => string '2014-01-11 16:31:46' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
      'groupDate' => string '2014-01-11' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      'lastLogin' => 
        object(DateTime)[988]
          public 'date' => string '2013-10-15 21:05:31' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
      'groupDate' => string '2013-10-15' (length=10)
  2 =>
```

But when i pass the query to paginator i am getting:

```
Notice: Undefined index: groupDate in /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php line 2197
```

Using:

```
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.3.3",
    "knplabs/knp-components": "1.2.4"
```

What am i missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem has solved. My query result was not compatible with KNP i guess so what i did ?

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $query,
```

Changed to

```
$result = $query->getResult();    

$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $result,
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Here are some solutions and similar issue 
http://www.programmingrelief.com/4151523/Symfony2-Doctrine-Group-By
[Symfony2 doctrine GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119485/symfony2-doctrine-group-by)

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id),
u.lastLogin,
DATE(u.lastLogin) AS groupDate 
CAST(u.lastLogin as date) AS HIDDEN groupDateGrp 
FROM UserBundle:User u 
GROUP BY DATE(groupDateGrp) 
ORDER BY u.lastLogin DESC
```

Comment: can you check if your query is returning some data ?

Comment: Another issue you have UserBundle:User I suppose it should be just User, I have updated the answer.

Comment: No, it should be UserBundle:User i write it like this in every DQL query. + i am getting error when i tried just User as you suggested.

Comment: ok just echo the query and see what it gives without Hidden and with UserBundle, something as echo $dql;

Comment: object(Doctrine\ORM\Query)[918]
  private '_state' => int 2
  private '_dql' => string 'SELECT COUNT(u.id),u.lastLogin, DATE(u.lastLogin) AS groupDate FROM UserBundle:User u GROUP BY groupDate ORDER BY u.lastLogin DESC' (length=130)

Comment: Your query looks good, and using the UserBundle:User should read the table as defined. I have created a test http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03a65/1 with your query and looks good. Can you check historyLoginAction() if the query is getting executed, looks like its not getting executed and while trying to get data for index "groupDate" its throwing an error.